# Error when posting achievements with user messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, achievements

When posting an achievement with a user message it gives the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) You haven't enabled User Messages for this action type (127701393971353) yet. Please update your Open Graph settings in the App Dashboard","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

No clue where to enable that.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-action-type/, “Configure Optional Properties”

Comment: 'in the App Dashboard', this is the name of the tool for managing your app settings at developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: Any luck solving this?  I'm having the same problem, I think perhaps they're including this error message when the problem is really something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get access to the setting by modifying the url manually with the id.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your_app_id_here/opengraph/action_type/127701393971353/

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else, I had this issue.  My situation was: I had a live app with an approved Open Graph action. I needed to release a new version of the app but I needed a new Open Graph action for this so the earlier version still worked until users upgraded to the new version. When I used the new Open Graph action, I got this error. My problem was that I had made a simple typo error in the bundle id of the new app version so it didn't match with the bundle id I had specified for the iOS settings in the Basic Settings page in the Facebook Developer app. The clue was that in the error given in the Xcode debug console, the app id didn't match up.